# cordova receiving GCM registrationId = null

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I am trying to get a RegistrationID from the GCM service.
All i can see in Logcat is an empty string: "registrationId = null".
Does the Project name of the Google API have to match the apps name?
The documentation says:

> For example, an Android app is identified by the package name from the manifest. This ensures that the messages are targeted to the correct Android app.

I do not exactly understand which names are being compared to each other...

My code is based on this [PushPlugin example](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#automatic_installation):

```
        var pushNotification;

        function onDeviceReady() {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                if( $("#home").length > 0)
                {
                    // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                    //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
                else
                {
                    navigator.app.backHistory();
                }
            }, false);

            try 
            { 
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
          $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
                if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||
                        device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"960122754475","ecb":"onNotification"});        // required!
                } else {
                    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                }
            }
            catch(err) 
            { 
                txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                alert(txt); 
            } 
        }

        // handle APNS notifications for iOS
        function onNotificationAPN(e) {
            if (e.alert) {
                 $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                 // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
                 navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
            }

            if (e.sound) {
                // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                snd.play();
            }

            if (e.badge) {
                pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
            }
        }

        // handle GCM notifications for Android
        function onNotification(e) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

            switch( e.event )
            {
                case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                }
                break;

                case 'message':
                    // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                    // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                    if (e.foreground)
                    {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                            // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                                // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                                var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                                // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                                // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                                var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);

                        my_media.play();
                    }
                    else
                    {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                        if (e.coldstart)
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        else
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    }

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                    //android only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    //amazon-fireos only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                break;

                case 'error':
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                break;

                default:
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                break;
            }
        }

        function tokenHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
            // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
        }

        function successHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
        }

        function errorHandler (error) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
        }

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

It´s a problem of the android emulator.
Since Testing it on a real device, everything works fine.

> Important - Push notifications are intended for real devices. They are not tested for WP8 Emulator. The registration process will fail on the iOS simulator. Notifications can be made to work on the Android Emulator, however doing so requires installation of some helper libraries, as outlined [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/), under the section titled "Installing helper libraries and setting up the Emulator" - https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin